# React prevent button in form to be clicked on hitting return

Tags: reactjs

I have a Login component like this :

```
type Props = {
    onForgotPassword: (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
};

    class Login extends React.Component<Props, State> {

        constructor(props: Props) {
            super(props);
        }

        handleSubmit(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
            e.preventDefault();
            ...
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div
                >
                    <Form
                        onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                        layout="vertical"
                    >
                                <input
                                    type="email"
                                />
                                <button
                                    type="button"
                                    onClick={this.props.onForgotPassword}
                                >
                                    Forgot password ?
                                </button>
                            <button
                                type="submit"
                            >
                                         <span>Submit</span>
                            </button>
                    </Form>
                </div>
            );

        }
    }
```

And when I hit enter after editing the email input, the button forgot password is clicked.

I want the form to be submitted instead.

The function onForgotPassword looks like this :

```
const changeForm = (v: AuthForm) => (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setForm(v);
};


<Login onForgotPassord={changeForm(Form.ForgotPassword)} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution :

```
type Props = {
    onForgotPassword: (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLButtonElement> | React.KeyboardEvent) => void;
};

const changeForm = (v: AuthForm) => (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLButtonElement> | React.KeyboardEvent) => {
    if(e instanceof KeyboardEvent && e.key === 'Enter'){ 
        return;
    }
    setForm(v);
};
```